# Waypoint set too high up after inserting new DOM element

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/): When inserting new elements onto the page (such as error messages) the vertical scroll waypoint is set higher than before.

```
addWayPoints: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.$('.table-waypoint').waypoint({
                offset: 0,
                handler: function (direction) {
                    self.$hiddenHeadings.toggleClass('visible', direction === 'down');
                }
            });

            this.$('.table-end-waypoint').waypoint({
                offset: 165,
                handler: function (direction) {
                    self.$hiddenHeadings.toggleClass('visible', direction === 'up');
                }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [Waypoint.refreshAll()](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/refresh-all/) after you toggle the headings' class to recalculate the trigger points of all waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that setting a waypoint sets it to a pixel height from the top or bottom when you define the element as a scrollpoint, so it is not a dynamic point at which the waypoint is attached to.

You need to reset the waypoints after adding or removing a DOM element.

```
        addWayPoints: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.$('.table-waypoint').waypoint({
                offset: 0,
                handler: function (direction) {
                    self.$hiddenHeadings.toggleClass('visible', direction === 'down');
                }
            });

            this.$('.table-end-waypoint').waypoint({
                offset: 165,
                handler: function (direction) {
                    self.$hiddenHeadings.toggleClass('visible', direction === 'up');
                }
            });
        },

        resetWaypoints: function (){
            Waypoint.destroyAll();
            this.addWayPoints();
        },
```

Comment: This is what `Waypoint.refreshAll()` is for. You don't have to destroy and recreate them. Doing so may have unintended consequences since recreating them may cause them to fire if you're already scrolled down the page.

Comment: Thanks for the info, tried it out and it works fine. I think I just had trouble finding some of the docs on your site. Add this as an answer and Ill happily accept.